# What just happened to our design? Visited links are now blue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

**Regression** This was fixed (per the answer below0 and has broken again, on main and meta (August 2015).  And then was fixed again and is now broken again (October 2015).

Our nice, soft, shades-of-brown site theme has just been invaded by the blue end of the spectrum:

[image: screen shot]

Visited links are now blue where they used to be a lighter brown than the unvisited ones.

Firefox and Chrome on Mac OS 10.6, main and meta.  Also happens in Chrome on my Android phone (in full rather than mobile view).  I think this probably isn't local to me, though if it is I expect I'll hear about that. :-)

It also affects the "box" around user cards:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: This is also true when using Safari in OS X.10

Comment: Also username links are blue, instead of orange

Comment: It's back to normal for me now.  @NoachmiFrankfurt, Shokhet -- you too?

Comment: I noticed as much

Comment: I'm marking this status-completed, though I'm still curious about what caused it (should anybody who knows wander by and be willing to expend a few sentences to enlighten me).

Comment: Back to normal, just came back to say as much to find it's already [status-completed] :)

Comment: Now we have blue links on Meta MY -- does this need a new [tag:bug] post?

Comment: Actually, it's the same on MY main also...are we in the middle of being moved to the new design?

Comment: The profile pages look funny also....

Comment: See also http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23346463#23346463 et seqq

Comment: It appears that everything is back in order, main, meta, and profiles. No new design, though `:-(`

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263461/266359

Comment: @shokhet thanks for the update. I'm on mobile right now so can't easily verify; if it's fixed feel free to ask a mod to mark status-completed.

Comment: Like @Shokhet, I, too see normal display behavior now (and did see the incorrect behavior previously).

Comment: As of last night, I was getting the blue links on my fancy new upgraded Windows 10 - Edge browser. I don't remember if it was like that the last couple times I accessed MY with the Edge browser, but I assume it wasn't, otherwise I wouldn't have noticed it this time ;)

Comment: This just happened to me again.

Comment: @Daniel I'm seeing it now too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that. We accidentally [a wrong file in another file](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267281/155160).

Comment: Oops.  Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from [this answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259186/162102):

> We rolled out a new image uploader today. Unfortunately, the design was targeted at the new-design sites only, and so the image uploader stopped working (at all) on the old-design sites.
>
> In a hurry to get the image uploader working, we grafted the new image uploader styles to the old base styles. This had some of the side effects you noticed. We have since fixed these side effects. My sincere gratitude to our design team for helping out with this in off-hours!

Mi Yodeya is an "old-design" site.   Eventually all sites will be on the "new design", which enables the new profile you've probably seen on other sites on the network and that we're sadly lacking here.  The new design involves what I understand to be mostly-invisible changes in how the CSS is put together.